# How to make the responsive textbox in popup window form

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I need a popup window for Signup option. So I used following coding,

```
<li onclick="document.getElementById('signUpId').style.display='block'" style="width:auto;"><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>Sign Up</a></li>
                    <div id="signUpId" class="signUpClass">                     
                        <form class="signUp-content animate" style="border:1px solid #ccc">
                            <div class="container">
                                <p class="close" onclick="document.getElementById('signUpId').style.display='none'" style="width:auto;">&times;</p>
                                <h1>Sign Up</h1>
                                <p>Please fill in this form to create an account.</p>
                                <hr>

                                <label for="email"><b>Email</b></label>
                                <input class="textInput_Sign" type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" required>

                                <label for="psw"><b>Password</b></label>
                                <input class="pwInput_Sign" type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required>

                                <label for="psw-repeat"><b>Repeat Password</b></label>
                                <input class="repeatPwInput_Sign" type="password" placeholder="Repeat Password" name="psw-repeat" required>

                                <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="remember" style="margin-bottom:15px"> Remember me
                                </label>

                                <p>By creating an account you agree to our <a href="#" style="color:dodgerblue">Terms & Privacy</a>.</p>

                                <div class="clearfix">
                                    <button type="button" class="cancelbtn" onclick="document.getElementById('signUpId').style.display='none'">Cancel</button>
                                    <button type="submit" class="signupbtn">Sign Up</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
```

But, not able to make responsive text box in popup window form.[image]

[image]

Can anybody help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Please check this link to check how bootstrap works : 
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/

Answer (score 0):

Try to give them input fields a width of 100%

Comment: input[type=text], input[type=password] {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}                                                                                                                                           I tried this style. But, its not working

Comment: Can you post your css for forms

Answer (score -1):

With bootstrap, you just need to add the class "form-control" to the input elements.